# Paypal Express Checkout: Recurring payments on specific date

Tags: javascript, paypal

I am attempting to setup our website to accept recurring payments on a specific date (£5 on 1st June every year) regardless of when the user initially signs up (except for the month of May, then thier first rebill will be on 1st June the following year)

My searches so far have yielded that Express Checkout (checkout.js) is probably my best option.

I have managed to, in sandbox mode, take the initial payment of £5, but can't find any documentation on how to setup the recurring payment.

Code below

```js
paypal.Button.render(
    {
        env: "sandbox", // 'production' Or 'sandbox',

        // Pass the client ids to use to create your transaction on sandbox and production environments

        client: {
            sandbox:
                [REDACTED], // from https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/
            production:
                [REDACTED] // from https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/
        },

        // Pass the payment details for your transaction
        // See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_create for the expected json parameters

        payment: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.payment.create({
                transactions: [
                    {
                        amount: {
                            total: "5.00",
                            currency: "GBP"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
        },

        // Display a "Pay Now" button rather than a "Continue" button

        commit: true,

        // Pass a function to be called when the customer completes the payment

        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(actions);
            return actions.payment.execute().then(function(response) {
                console.log("The payment was completed!");
            });
        },

        // Pass a function to be called when the customer cancels the payment

        onCancel: function(data) {
            console.log("The payment was cancelled!");
        }
    },
    "#paypal-button"
);
```